Is there a command line to enable Options > C/C++ Compiler > Language 1, select Auto (extension-based), in IAR for building (.cpp) file
I want to automatically build IAR project using python script and I want to enable  Options > C/C++ Compiler > Language 1, select Auto (extension-based) but I am unable to find  any command line option to do so.
I have gone through all the c/c++ development document of IAR but still found nothing or is there  any python module that can be used to automate setting in IAR.
Please can anyone help me with this??

"IAR" would be the "IAR embedded workbench for Arm"? Surely you can just invoke the compiler directly instead of going through the IDE? Suggest you look at Cmake for your build system.

Yes IAR embedded workbench for Arm

.. and my other question? Are you sure you need to go through the IDE?

Actually I am appending the build command in the CFLAGS  to automate the settings using scons environment but didn't find any command regarding auto extension language

Surely scons is smart enough to figure out the language from the extension?

If you have both C and C++ code, you will need a separate CXXFLAGS macro for C++ compilation.  If you specify --c++ in combination with options that apply only to C compilation, the compiler rejects it.  Alternatively remove the C compilation options and accept that all your code will compile as C++ even if it has a .c extension.  That may not work if you have used C features that deviate from the subset that is also valid C++, and some constructs may have subtly different semantics.

@Clifford I have added --c++ in CXXFLAGS but i am getting this error.  [Su004]: Illegal combination: --use_c++_inline and --c++

@Alibaba that is a different question best dealt with by posting a new question with the associated build script or makefile.

There is no automatic language selection in any of the Iar command line compilers. To compile a file as C++ you must add the --c++ flag to the command line.

I have done added --c++ but it is giving error . [Su004]: Illegal combination: --use_c++_inline and --c++.  I have no where added --use_c++_inline in any of the flags

@Alibaba My only suggestion is that you check the actual command line sent to the compiler. AFAIK --use_c++_inline is not implied by any other command line option.

--use_c++_inline is a switch for C compilation, in C++ it will do that in implicitly.  Rather over-fastidious error checking, since for C++ the switch could simply be ignored as benign/no effect.  Nothing I learn about this compiler makes me want to use it!
